# Assets management

Tags: assets

I would like to use the [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) service on Craft CMS assets tag. Also I would like to use AI tags, so I would like to store it on the Assets.

Is that possible to do it, or it is better to create a new section type, which has Asset, and I am decorating the extra fields what I needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the craft cms 3 documentation on github:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets.html

So for the assets I can add fields, which could hold the information what I need!